# if __FILE__ == $0 problem with main

Tags: ruby

Im currently working on a project for my first course in Ruby. A part of the assignment is to have a main class as the one below. I have it in a separate file and the other modules and classes are in separate files. Now Im getting an uninitialized constant Main::Camping (NameError) which I dont get. Any clues to why?! Thanks

Regards

```
class Main  

if __FILE__ == $0   
    $camping = Camping.new(32, 12)  #creates a new camping     

    include Menus
    $current_menu = main_menu

    # loops through the menu
    while (true)
        puts $current_menu
        choice = Menus.get_input
        $current_menu.make_menu_choice(choice)
    end
end
```

end

Comment: I've never seen a "if __FILE__ == $0" inside a class. The whole code looks weird to me: an include in the middle of the code, global variables, infinite loops without breaks...

Comment: @tokland: Im sure you are right. I am just a beginner to Ruby. How would you do it? Regards

Comment: well, first the __FILE__ code must be at the end of the script, outside the Main class, and it should only create a Main instance and run it; all the logic must be inside the Main class. And don't use global variables, it's the path to the dark side!

Comment: So I suspected, about global variables:) the thing is that now my main function is in a separate file and. I removed the class wrapping it and currently using a loop do..end instead of the while(true). Still dont know how to do it without the global variables though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the file that defines `Camping` or '`Menu`'? You will need to '`require`' those files:

```
require 'camping'
require 'menus' # etc

class Main
#..
```

Read more about require [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005941).

Comment: Oh! I forgot, thats true. Now its working, thanks! Did you think that it was strange to us while (true)? You made a comment about it. Regards

Comment: @Tim, consder the construct "loop do...end" as an alternative to "while (true)...end"

Comment: @Wayne: do you mean something like this then: loop do puts $current_menu choice = Menus.get_valid_input($current_menu.options)
   $current_menu.make_menu_choice(choice)
  end

Comment: @Tim, yes.  They do the same thing, but "loop do...end" is more common for endless loops.

Comment: @Wayne, thank you for your answer. I looked it up and it worked well. Maybe I should not create an endless loop?! I saw it incorporated with break if as well. Ill see how I will proceed. Regards

Comment: @Tim, Use an endless loop if that seems best. Later, you will develop opinions on whether and when to use endless loops, but it's not time for opinions when you're still learning the basics.

Comment: @Wayne, yes I guess you are right about that. As long as it works for me now. And it does. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Wayne: "but it's not time for opinions when you're still learning the basics" Yes, well said.